# Linq To Sql - DataContext.SubmitChanges() problem

Tags: linq-to-sql, submitchanges

I have a code like this.

DBContext is Datacontext instance.

```
try
            {
                TBLORGANISM org = new TBLORGANISM();
                org.OrganismDesc = p.Subject;
                DBContext.TBLORGANISMs.InsertOnSubmit(org);
                DBContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

At this point, I want to IGNORE the error and want to be skipped. Not to be retried.
But when I try another insert like

```
                TBLACTION act = new TBLACTION();
                act.ActionDesc = p.ActionName;
                DBContext.TBLACTIONs.InsertOnSubmit(act);
                DBContext.SubmitChanges();
```

SubmitChanges firstly retries previous attempt.

How can I tell "skip errors, don't try again"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new instance of DBContext the second time.

But why do you want to skip errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: DBContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict).
Hope it will help.